# Is it possible to run java program without class?

Tags: java

Yes I know that java is fully object oriented but i want to know that is there any possibility of executing java code without class??

Comment: Do you mean like a command line interpreter like python ?

Comment: I think "no."  The JVM validates your files before it executes them.  I don't believe there's any way to induce it to run something that wasn't a valid class.

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're asking. Maybe tell us why using "class" is a problem for you?

Comment: Java code can't exist outside a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java 9 you have REPL which allows you to write code by typing code fragments.

However, even though you don't have to write all the code for a `class` the code is wrapped in a class in reality.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no. (With, of course, the partial exception of the situation described by Peter Lawrey). In Java *everything* is an object - there is no concept of code that isn't associated with one.